# ASP.NET MVC pass an object from table to the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass a model to the controller after klicking on a row.

this is my code which doesn't work.

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        <p>Sender</p>
    </th>
    <th>
        <p>Subject</p>
    </th>
    <th>
        <p>Received</p>
    </th>
    <th>
        <p>HasAttachment</p>
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Inbox) {
<tr class="mail-row" onclick="location.href = '@(Html.ActionLink   ("", "MailViewer", "Profile", new { mail = item }, null ))'">
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sender)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subject)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Received)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HasAttachment)
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

I tried to use Url.Action but i got only the Object Type in the url and not    the actual object.

I try to send this object:

```
public class Mail
{
    public string Sender { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public DateTime Received { get; set; }
    public bool HasAttachment { get; set; }

    public string content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can only send primitive datatypes with `Url.Action`. I would put all primitive types required for your object into your `Url.Action` and serialize the object in your controller.

Comment: why not send ID or a primary key to the controller and handle in controller to send the model back.

Comment: So is it not possible to pass an object through http url ?

Comment: it is possible but what are you trying to send can you give example?

Comment: You could attach a jquery click event to your row and then send the row data (item) as a part of the jquery post to your controller. Will be much simpler

Comment: It needs to be `@Url.Action("MailViewer", "Profile", item)` and each property of item will be serialized. But you should not be doing that (apart from the ugly query string, and the fact it will not work if any of the properties are complex objects, you risk exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception). Just pass the ID of the item.

Answer (score 2):

it is possible with `json` but you will but you should send `id` and get the data in action based on that `id` but with `json` you can do it like this

My action link will be

```
@Html.ActionLink("senddata", "MailViewer",new{ @data = Json.Encode(item)  } )
```

and my action will be something like this

```
public ActionResult MailViewer(string data)
        {
            var result = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<Mail>(data);

            return View();

        }
```